# Prevent Spinner Item to Draw Behind AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview, spinner, android-alertdialog

I have a custom `AlertDialog` with a view is populated with `DialogFragment`. This fragment contains a `ListView` that contains a `Spinner`. Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

The problem is when I scroll through the items and select the spinner, occasionally, it will draws its item list behind the dialog, like so:

[image]

I think somehow, when the list is still scrolling, defined by `SCROLL_STATE_FLING` state, the item's kinda *loses its parent* for a while.

I was thinking of a solution that is to set the view unfocusable till the scrolling has finished, as follows:

```
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                view.setFocusable(true);
            } else {
                view.setFocusable(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```

But still, the problem persists. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by moving from `ListView` to `RecyclerView`. There must be something going on with the `ListView`’s behavior